# Host seems down Nmap?

Tags: networking, ping, nmap

I'm currently running Nmap 7.50

I'm trying to execute the following command:

```
nmap -p 1-65535 -T4 -A -v IP
```

But when I do that it says:

> Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes

I don't want to use `-Pn` since that will hide the ports. It works at my jobs internet, any chance this has to do with my router? I allowed it in my firewall.

If you need more information please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Windows firewall blocks pings from networks other than its own by default, and probably even the ones on its own network.  If you mean you enabled it in Windows Firewall, you have to be sure you enable it for whichever category (external network or the same network).

I'm not sure what you mean that -Pn will block ports; it should show you open ports just fine.  It just makes nmap assume it will work fine without the ping discovery.

Comment: I "gave nmap permission" in my firewall. Also -Pn takes forever to scan and I was wondering why it would work at my job's internet but not at home. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `-Pn` doesn't change the duration, except to make it shorter (.01 seconds shorter in my test scan just now).  The reason that scan takes so long is mostly because you're using `-p 1-65535`.

Comment: Giving nmap outbound permission is a start, but what kind of thing are you scanning, is it on a different network, is there NAT involved?

Comment: Its on a different network, Im scanning a minecraft server for a friend of mine to scan for bugs that can break their server. But I can't scan properly or something. Im going to try -Pn a few times. I will tell you if it worked or not

Comment: Okay, so it didn't help anything, scanning is wayyyy faster without -Pn. But without -Pn it doesn't work, it takes up to 2 HOURS to scan all these ports. Please help.

Comment: The only thing -Pn does is stop the ping probe.  If they were permitting ICMP (pings) then it would go through and scanning all those ports would still take just as long.  Since you're trying to scan for a particular service like Minecraft, then scan only that port, so `-p 25565` by default (or whatever port they decided to host it on in server.properties or forwarded through to the server).  Scanning every single port every scan is what's making it take so long, and unless you're intentionally watching for new obscure ports to open, it's also a waste of time.

Comment: Side-note, I'm not sure what Minecraft server 'bugs' you'd find with nmap, unless your friend were using a suspicious cracked server .jar that also maliciously opened backdoor ports.

Comment: There are a lot of bugs going on with ports and minecraft, thats why I want to see every open ports. But you said something about ICMP? I have read about this before, how can I fix this?

Comment: Your friend would need to allow ICMP to hit the server by configuring both the router and the box the server runs on.  The particular configuration will depend greatly on their setup.  Please allow me to reiterate:  Allowing ICMP to hit the server will not speed the scan up.  If merely checking if the port is open is your goal, you can speed the scan by ditching the `-A` option and using `-sS` instead.  Keep in mind, if their router is NATing to the server, only the forwarded ports will actually hit the box.  You'd have to scan from within the network to hit every port in that case.

Comment: I'm curious as to what leads you to where you are now.  What specific information are you thinking the scan will get you?  What specifically do you think is wrong (or could be)?  Personally, if I were setting up a server and wanted to know if it were accessible, I'd just try `nmap -sS -Pn -p 25565` or use `nmap -p 25565 --script=[the script in the link I'm about to provide]` with this script:  https://github.com/sjhilt/Nmap-NSEs/blob/master/minecraft-info.nse

Comment: Its giving ports connected to a bungeecord server, by bypassing the main port you can use an exploit/hack called ForceOP.

Comment: Preliminary searches indicate that only works on a cracked server.  Being able to log in as other players (the main mechanism forceop exploits) is a known vulnerability of cracked servers, and is the price you pay to avoid the (low) price of Minecraft.  If there is something about bungeecord that leaves one vulnerable on legitimate servers, the solution is to block all ports except the one bungee with the OS' built-in firewall.  I see then why you would want to scan.  Try nmap all ports with -sS and then scan deeper on only the open ones individually.

Comment: Alright, how much i'd like to try this, my scan doesn't work without -Pn, it still says "host seems down"??

Comment: Update the question with the terminal output including the command.  I'd recommend replacing the last two or three octets of the target IP with x characters.  Also any details you can provide about the destination server would help, like is it owned by a 3rd party, does your friend have administrative control of the router it's on, is that router configured to NAT, what ports does it forward, etc.